# Exporting an Universal Windows App as an EXE file in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

I have written a program using Visual Studio 2019 ( *Universal Windows Project* ) and I want to export it as a MS Windows executable file. I searched it once, but I couldn't find any answer to do that. If anyone knows how to do that, please reply me.
Thanks

Comment: you need to create a [APPX file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#generate-an-app-package) that you can install via app installer

Comment: I created a file named ' Package.appinstaller '. Did I do what you meant? If yes, What should I do now?

Comment: no, rightclick on UWP project in solution and choose Publish->Create App Packages (before Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3, the Publish menu is named Store).

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But still I have a question : What is the certificate I created used for?

Comment: this is required to [sideload the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-create-a-package-signing-certificate): "You must digitally sign your packaged Windows apps before you deploy them."

Comment: Thanks. It is working without any problem.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that [you can accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the App on other Windows 10 devices, you need to create an [AppX installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#generate-an-app-package) package.

Select the UWP app in solution explorer, Right-click the project and choose Publish->Create App Packages (before Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3, the Publish menu is named Store).

[image]

Now check Sideloading:

[image]

On the target device, install the [generated certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-create-a-package-signing-certificate#remarks) and make a double click on the appx file to install the app.